# Injecting Vault secrets into a few Kubernetes Clusters

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

Good afternoon, colleagues.
Please tell me.
I set up the k8s+vault integration according to the instructions: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar

But I have a test and production Kubernetes cluster and only one Vault.
Is it possible to integrate one Vault with multiple Kubernetes clusters?

Find parameter: authPath: "auth/kubernetes", mayby for second cluster make:
authPath: "auth/kubernetes2" .. etc

Comment: Yes. Do you have a question about an obstacle encountered while attempting to implement that?

Comment: not yet succeeded.
Find this in vault-agent-injector
    Environment:
      AGENT_INJECT_VAULT_AUTH_PATH:                        auth/kubernetes               trying to solve the problem

Comment: fix (AGENT_INJECT_VAULT_AUTH_PATH: auth/kubernetes), i make --set "authPath=auth/prod-kubernetes", but need: --set "injector.authPath=auth/prod-kubernetes".        but still doesn't work either.

Comment: vault dooesn't create entities and aliases

Comment: Thank you it worked!    My last mistake, I created the auth method through the GUI, but I had to:  vault auth enable -path prod-kubernetes kubernetes

Answer (score 3):

It's possible what needs to be done:

```
helm install vault hashicorp/vault \
    --set "injector.externalVaultAddr=http://external-vault:8200" --set "authPath=auth/kubernetesnew"

vault auth enable -path kubernetesnew kubernetes
..

vault write auth/kubernetesnew/role/k8s-name-role \
    bound_service_account_names=k8s-vault-sa \
    bound_service_account_namespaces=k8s-vault-namespace \
    ttl=24h
```